# CALayer mask property

Tags: ios, calayer, mask, quartz-core

I found this line confusing?

> When configuring a mask, remember to set the size and position of the mask layer to ensure it is aligned properly with the layer it masks.

What align means here? Does it means that you have to provide a mask that as a frame equal the bounds of the masked layer? Does it means that you can't be outside the visible part of the bounds of the masked layer?

Comment: The mask layer lives in the masked layer's coordinate system just as if it were a sublayer.

Comment: Ok, that is a good explanation. I'm aware of that and i found confusing the sentence above.
If you want to add this as a answer i'll accept It